# VCPKG: list available versions of a package

Tags: vcpkg

For example, how can I list available GDAL library versions ?
They are not listed on VCPKG packages website neither by `vcpkg search gdal`command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this! it is a quick fix until vcpkg supports pkgs version listing. https://github.com/hamaney/vcpkg_version_finder.

on a related note:
to look up a package by name and get the latest available version of it use `vcpkg search <pkg name>`

UPDATE SEP-11-2021:
I just found out that you can use the experimental flag `x-history`. for example `vcpkg x-history <pkg name>` (you might need an internet connection the first time you run this command).

**UPDATE JAN-01-2024**:
The `x-history` option is no longer available.

Comment: No longer a valid option as of the time of writing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use https://vcpkg.link/ in order to find all the versions of a package and when it got released (e.g. https://vcpkg.link/ports/gdal/versions for `gdal`). Besides, you can also see from which version a given feature has been introduced by looking at the overview of a package.

Disclosure: I'm the creator of the platform.

Comment: But even though we can find previous versions on your site, how do we install it so that vcpkg could recognize it?